# Why is my Javascript object member being initialized to onThen before the constructor?

Tags: javascript, firefox

This is my code:

```
SLVD.promise = function() {
    delete this.data;
    delete this.callBack;
    delete this.babyPromise;
};
SLVD.promise.prototype.then = function(callBack) {
    if(this.data) {
        return callBack(this.data);
    }
    else {
        this.callBack = callBack;

        this.babyPromise = new SLVD.promise();

        return this.babyPromise;
    }
};
SLVD.promise.prototype.resolve = function(data) {
    if(this.callBack) {
        var tPromise = this.callBack(data);

        if(this.babyPromise) {
            if(!(tPromise instanceof SLVD.promise)) {
                this.babyPromise.resolve(tPromise);
            }
            else if(tPromise.data) {
                this.babyPromise.resolve(tPromise.data);
            }
            else {
                tPromise.callBack = this.babyPromise.callBack;
                if(this.babyPromise.babyPromise) {
                tPromise.babyPromise = this.babyPromise.babyPromise;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        this.data = data;
    }
};
SLVD.promise.as = function(data) {
    var promise = new SLVD.promise();
    promise.resolve(data);
    return promise;
};
```

It's a promise system. (Yes, I am aware there are already promise systems out there. Please don't bug me on that.) However, when the constructor is run, the member callBack is already set to "onThen(value)." And when I try deleting it in the constructor as below, it still does it. Does anyone know anything about this?

Other potentially helpful information:

- The call to the constructor is new SLVD.promise();
- I gave the entirety of the class definition. There is no inheritance, and I have no other hidden prototype properties.
- I have done a search in files in notepad++ for onThen; I definitely have never used that name.
- I am running this in Firefox.
- I tried renaming callBack to weird things in case it was a reserved word of sorts, but it didn't help.

This image shows the code paused in the debugger on the line after I call delete in the constructor...
[image: Weird error]

EDIT: For that matter, this.babyPromise is also predefined...(even after the delete). Why?

Comment: Don't use delete, it slows everything down. Instead change the value to null or 0 or an empty string or anything falsey.

Comment: That's not the problem though. Nothing should be pre-defined in the constructor call.

Comment: Please show us how you call this code and how it is used since that is likely a key to understanding your problem.  For example are you always creating a new object or are you reusing the same object?

Comment: When I ran that code in an empty page, I did not get any errors. just an empty object.

Comment: @jfriend00 I used this `var colemc = new SLVD.promise();`

Comment: If that's all there is to the code, then your observation is flawed in some way because a brand new `SLVD.promise()` object won't have any members other than what's on the prototype.

Comment: var promise = new SLVD.promise();

Comment: I did extensive testing on this system on an empty page, and it worked. I don't understand why it wouldn't work now. I also tried colecmc's suggestion to use this.callBack = undefined to no avail.

Comment: Also, I have a breakpoint on the code such that I know the variable is being initialized by the constructor the very first time.

Comment: There's clearly something else going on in your page (perhaps conflicting variables or code) that you aren't disclosing.  The issue is to figure out what else is influencing it.  See here in a vanilla execution where your issue does not occur: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7rayw5cc/

Comment: I think I've narrowed it down to it being some kind of issue with Firebug (v 2.0.11). The behavior has been very inconsistent--sometimes working and other times not.

Comment: That's not a promise system, that some callback code with method named `then`. Please don't use that code in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, the issue turned out to be some issue with Firebug (v 2.0.11). I switched over to using Chrome and its debugger, and I haven't had any problems like this since then.